# Constrained Network Maximum Flow

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, directed-graph, bipartite

Long time ago, I wrote the following Python module based on an algorithm described into an academic paper I cannot find anymore (pretty sorry for the lack of credits, citations, etc..., but I forgot to mention the source in the script comments).

Basically, it allows to reconstruct a bipartite network knowing only its marginals (row and column sums) and the probabilities of the existance of a link (that part seems only partially implemented, if not at all) by using a maximum flow approach based on the Edmonds-Karp algorithm:

```
# IMPORTS

import numpy as np

from heapq import (
    heappop,
    heappush
)

# CLASSES

class HeapPair:

    def __init__(self, v1, v2):
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from [self.v1, self.v2]

    def __lt__(self, other):

        if self.v1 != other.v1:
            return self.v1 > other.v1

        return self.v2 > other.v2

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'HeapPair'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f'({self.v1}, {self.v2})')

# FUNCTIONS

def max_flow_matrix(size: int, rows: np.ndarray, columns: np.ndarray, probabilities: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:

    s = 0
    t = (size * 2) + 1
    vertices = (size * 2) + 2

    e = np.zeros((vertices, size), dtype=int)
    capacity = np.zeros((vertices, vertices), dtype=float)
    flow = np.zeros((vertices, vertices), dtype=float)

    for i in range(size):
        e[s, i] = i + 1
        e[t, i] = size + i + 1
        e[size + i + 1, 0] = t

        capacity[s, i + 1] = rows[i]
        capacity[size + i + 1, t] = columns[i]

    offsets = {i + 1: 1 for i in range(size * 2)}

    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if probabilities[i, j] > 0.0:

                a = i + 1
                b = size + j + 1

                e[a, offsets[a]] = b
                e[b, offsets[b]] = a
                capacity[a, b] = np.Inf

                offsets[a] += 1
                offsets[b] += 1

    while True:

        colour = np.zeros(vertices, dtype=int)
        colour[s] = 1

        d = np.repeat(2 * vertices, vertices)
        d[s] = 0

        pred = np.repeat(-1, vertices)
        Q = [HeapPair(0, s)]

        while (len(Q) > 0) and (colour[t] == 0):
            q, u = heappop(Q)

            if colour[u] == 1:
                colour[u] = 2

                for v in e[u]:

                    if (colour[v] == 0) and (capacity[u, v] > (flow[u, v] - flow[v, u] + 1e-8):
                        colour[v] = 1
                        pred[v] = u
                        d[v] = d[u] + 1

                        heappush(Q, HeapPair(-d[v], v))

                        if v == t:
                            break

                        if (v > 1 + size) and (capacity[v, t] > (flow[v, t] - flow[t, v] + 1e-8):
                            colour[t] = 1
                            pred[t] = v
                            d[t] = d[v] + 1
                            break

        if colour[t] == 0:
            break

        pos = t
        flow_new = capacity[pred[pos], pos] - flow[pred[pos], pos] + flow[pos, pred[pos]]
        pos = pred[pos]

        while pos != s:
            fmax = capacity[pred[pos], pos] - flow[pred[pos], pos] + flow[pos, pred[pos]]
            if fmax < flow_new:
                flow_new = fmax
            pos = pred[pos]

        pos = t

        while pos != s:
            flow[pred[pos], pos] += flow_new
            pos = pred[pos]

    res = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=float)

    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            res[i, j] = flow[i + 1, size + j + 1] - flow[size + j + 1, i + 1]

    return res
```

It works pretty well, indeed, although it lacks a check to see if the proposed reconstruction respects the contraints (it should not be too hard to implement, though). Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

size = 4
r = np.array([3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0])
c = np.array([2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0])

p = 0.5 * _np.ones((size, size), dtype=float)
np.fill_diagonal(p, 0.0)

n = max_flow_matrix(size, r, c, p)
print(n)

array([[0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [2., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

In more recent times, I started using [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) and, since it contains an implementation of the Edmonds-Karp maximum flow (documentation [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.edmonds_karp.html#networkx.algorithms.flow.edmonds_karp)), I was wondering if I can obtain the same result using it. This is what I tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

size = 4
r = np.array([3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0])
c = np.array([2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0])

p = 0.5 * _np.ones((size, size), dtype=float)
np.fill_diagonal(p, 0.0)

G = nx.DiGraph()

for n in ['source', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
    G.add_node(n, bipartite=0)

for n in [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 'sink']:
    G.add_node(n, bipartite=1)

for i in range(size):
    G.add_edge('source', i, capacity=r[i])
    G.add_edge(i + size, 'sink', capacity=c[i])

for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        if probabilities[i, j] > 0.0:
            G.add_edge(i, i + size)

R, flow_dict = nx.algorithms.flow.maximum_flow(G, 'source', 'sink', flow_func=nx.algorithms.flow.edmonds_karp)
```

My development stopped there. My knowledge of that area of NetworkX is kinda limited. I think the variable `flow_dict` contains what I'm looking for, but honestly I don't know if the problem has been correctly formulated and how to proceed to reassemble the final network from the flow data.

Comment: How do the probabilities factor in? Are you perhaps trying to maximize the sum of all probabilities of the edges you end up picking? If so, then this is an instance of minimum-cost maximum flow (which is available in NetworkX as `max_flow_min_cost`).